# Suppose that for $\theta \in R$ we have $f(z)=g(z,\theta)$. Now fix $z=z_0$, is $g(z_0,\theta)=f(z_0)$ for all $\theta$ in its domain?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, meromorphic-functions

Let $f(z)$ and $g(z,\theta)$ be complex functions with $f$ analytic and $g$ meromorphic. Suppose that for $\theta \in R$ we have $f(z)=g(z,\theta)$. Now    fix $z=z_0$, is  $g(z_0,\theta)=f(z_0)$ for all $\theta$  in its domain ?

I am supposing that they are equal by the identity theorem of meromorphic function but I am not sure

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: i am supposing that they are equal by the identity theorem of  meromorphic function

Comment: How can a function of $z,\theta$ be meromorphic?

Comment: Is $g(z,\theta)$ analytic function of $z$ and $\theta$?